# OpenGL cube coloring

Tags: android, opengl-es

I created a cube using OpenGL2.0. I want it has six different color on its each face. I followed some example and draw one cube. Everything goes well except the color of the cube. Color of each face mixed together and only red and green are shown. It looks really wired and I did't see any people have this problem same as me. Can anybody give me a hand? Below are my code and cube. Thank you so much!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl5EB.png)

```
public class MyCube {
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private ShortBuffer[] ArrayDrawListBuffer;
private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;

private int mProgram;

//For Projection and Camera Transformations
private final String vertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "attribute vec4 vColor;" +
                "varying vec4 vColorVarying;" +
                "void main() {" +
                // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "vColorVarying = vColor;"+
                "}";

// Use to access and set the view transformation
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "varying vec4 vColorVarying;"+
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColorVarying;" +
                "}";

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
float cubeCoords[] = {
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   // front top left 0
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,   // front bottom left 1
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,   // front bottom right 2
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,  // front top right 3
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,   // back top left 4
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,   // back top right 5
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,   // back bottom left 6
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  // back bottom right 7
        };


// Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };
float red[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
float blue[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

private short drawOrder[] = {
                                0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,//front
                                0, 4, 5, 0, 5, 3, //Top
                                0, 1, 6, 0, 6, 4, //left
                                3, 2, 7, 3, 7 ,5, //right
                                1, 2, 7, 1, 7, 6, //bottom
                                4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 5 //back
                                }; //(order to draw vertices)

final float cubeColor[] =
        {
                // Front face (red)
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

                // Top face (green)
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

                // Left face (blue)
                       0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

                // Right face (yellow)
                       1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

                // Bottom face (cyan)
                       0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

                // Back face (magenta)
                       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
        };


public MyCube() {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            cubeCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(cubeCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
            drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the color list
    ByteBuffer cb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
            cubeColor.length * 4);
    cb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    colorBuffer = cb.asFloatBuffer();
    colorBuffer.put(cubeColor);
    colorBuffer.position(0);


    int vertexShader = MyRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = MyRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            fragmentShaderCode);

    // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

    // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

    // creates OpenGL ES program executables
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
}

private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;

private final int vertexCount = cubeCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) { // pass in the calculated transformation matrix
    // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vColor");


    // Enable a handle to the cube vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    // Prepare the cube coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);


    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    //mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    // Enable a handle to the cube colors
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
    // Prepare the cube color data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 16, colorBuffer);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

    // Pass the projection and view transformation to the shader
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);


    // Draw the cube
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
    //GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);


    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mMVPMatrixHandle);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index buffer is used to index into the `colorBuffer` using the same index as is used for indexing into the `vertexBuffer`, so the corresponding elements in each need to match. The indices in your index buffer are in the range of 0-7, so you will only ever index the first 8 entries of your `colorBuffer`, which are green and red.

You need to have a separate index for every unique combination of vertex position and color. For each face there are 4 unique vertex-color combinations, so you will need 6 * 4 = 24 entries in your `cubeCoords` array and 24 matching entries in your `cubeColor` array.

Like this:

```
float cubeCoords[] = {

    // front face
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   // front top left 0
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,   // front bottom left 1
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,   // front bottom right 2
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,  // front top right 3

    // top face
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,   // back top left 4
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   // front top left 5
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,  // front top right 6
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,   // back top right 7

    // other faces...
}

final float cubeColor[] =
{
        // Front face (red)
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

        // Top face (green)
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

            // other faces...
}

private short drawOrder[] = {
                            0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,//front
                            4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, //Top
                            // other faces...
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding more dots to the color matrix, you can remove the extra colors and leave a color per vertex, that way the drawOrder. Though this will make the surface color a gradient between the different colors of the vertex.